# Use the Services-3.x node resource to create a new *unpublished* node

Tags: services

Is there a way that I can force a node to be unpublished by using the
node resource?

Requirement: Site A defines a content type 'item' which is published
by default. Site B needs to create 'item' nodes on A, and these
auto-created nodes should be unpublished.

```
function toolreq_test_create() {
$toolreq_endpoint = variable_get("toolreq_endpoint", "");
$options = toolreq_service_login();
if (!is_array($options)) {
    print "error<p>";
    return;
}
//create a node

$node_data = array(
                      "title"=>"DHC Tool 04 dev",
                      "type"=>"item",
                      //"status"=> FALSE, //ensure unpublished
                      "status" => 0,
                      "language" => "und", //lanugage neutral
                      "field_webpage"=>array(
                                                  "und"=>array(0=>array("url"=>"http://berkeley.edu",)
)
)
);

//use json
$options['headers']['content-type'] = "application/json";
$options['method'] = 'POST';
$options['data'] = json_encode($node_data);
$request = drupal_http_request($toolreq_endpoint . '/node', $options);
}
```

Since the node table's status field is the mysql INT type (with a
default of 1), I would think that I could pass status=>0 in the above
code, but doing that results in a *published* node. I have tried passing
0 using both JSON and x-www-form-urlencoded data.

If I use status=>FALSE and use JSON, the node is created as
unpublished, but I think that this is equivalent to inserting '' in the node.status field which results in a mysql warning:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `bamboodirt`.`node` (`nid`, `vid`, `type`, `language`, `title`, `uid`,
`status`, `created`, `changed`, `comment`, `promote`, `sticky`, `tnid`, `translate`) 
VALUES (NULL, 21, 'item', 'und', 'sql insert test', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 
'0');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                  |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'status' at row 1 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would live with that warning, but my webhost's mysql is less
permissive and I get a real error (durning node_save() I think) on
that server:

"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'status' at row 1"

(Here's the thread over at Pantheon http://help.getpantheon.com/pantheon/topics/json_node_create_works_on_localstack_fails_with_error_500_on_pantheon.)

Is there a way that I can force a node to be unpublished by using the
node resource, or do I need to write my own resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the 'status' field to `TRUE` or `FALSE` instead of `0` or `1`.

Comment: Using FALSE works as noted above. I think the FALSE/NULL value for status gets converted to 0 by MySQL. Common.inc L6833: 


    // Type cast to proper datatype, except when the value is NULL and the
    // column allows this.
    //
    // MySQL PDO silently casts e.g. FALSE and '' to 0 when inserting the value
    // into an integer column, but PostgreSQL PDO does not. Also type cast NULL
    // when the column does not allow this.